# Class not found from dependent jar on hot deploy in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment, jar

I have two eclipse projects:

1. Core classes shared with other projects packaged as a jar
2. A Webapp running on Tomcat 7 utilising the core classes jar and packaged as a war

Maven compiles and install the core classes as a jar into the local repository as expected. If I deploy to Tomcat with Maven everything is okay.

If I configure the Webapp on the Tomcat server in Eclipse I can hot deploy with no problems so long as I have the core project **closed in Eclipse**. Everything looks fine with the current core jar file deposited into the WEB-INF/lib folder on Tomcat.

However, when I have the core classes project **open in Eclipse** I have two problems:

1. I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for any class that is in the core jar
2. I noticed that the jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder is now a **directory** called "core.jar" with all the .java source files in it (i.e. no .class files)

I think that exploded jar is the problem but I've found no way to stop this behaviour other than to close the core project in Eclipse and watch the jar from the local maven repo be correctly placed in the lib folder.

I have tried manually adding the jar in the Eclipse build path and resource assembly screens but they cause other errors and besides. Eclipse has registered the dependency through Maven so the relationship is already there and I shouldn't need manual intervention.

Has anyone experience this problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

The question [Tomcat throws ClassNotFound exceptions for classes in other open eclipse projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603758/tomcat-throws-classnotfound-exceptions-for-classes-in-other-open-eclipse-project) had [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658721/80071) that worked for me:

> If you go to the project properties, pick the item "Deployment Assembly", click "Add..." and choose "Project", you can add the dependent project and the issue should be solved.