# Gradle multiple project build ClassNotFound on deploy

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

My web app is build using two projects one that contains the api and second web part. In Eclipse I am able to use classes from project-api in project-web however in deploy I have exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: project.api.TestApi
```

This is my main build.gradle file:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java' 
}
```

This is build.gradle from api:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

}
```

And this is part of my build.gradle from web:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':project-api')
...
}
```

If I go and see web app libraries I can't see anything like project-api.jar. Wham am I doing wrong?
UPDATE:
It is issue only in eclipse. If I run gradlew war and deploy this manually to tomcat I can deploy it without any issued. project-api.jar is included in war. I tried already to run few times

```
`gradlew clean cleanEclipse eclipse`
```

but it doesn't help. I also try to reimport projects in eclipse but still the same.
EDIT:
This project is a spring mvc app and I just discovered that when I build war from gradle I am able to deploy war manually without any errors. Issue is only when trying to deploy via eclipse. 
EDIT: Here is settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'project'
include 'project-test'
include 'project-web'
include 'project-api'
```

Comment: I don't know if android can do 1.7 (it couldn't a few months ago when I tried). What is you change it to 1.6?

Comment: I just updated post. I was not enough specific about issue. My bad.

Comment: can you post you settings.gradle?

Comment: added settings.gradle

Comment: does your web build.gradle have `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` in it?

Comment: no I have apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47517/discussion-between-ethan-and-john)

Comment: I have the same issue earlier and got a solution on the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12362410/2564329

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the dependencies of the deployable project to a "faceted project".

Project properties -> Project Facets -> Convert to faceted form...

Then mark each dependency as a "Utility Module".